# Order of dimensions for a multivariate (4d) normal distribution using scipy / python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, normal-distribution, probability-density

I would like to evaluate a 4d Gaussian / normal distribution on a 4d grid. Let's call the variables (x1,y1,x2,y2). Then if I have means = (x1=1,y1=0,x2=2,y2=0), I expect that when I do a 2d contour plot in the x1, x2 direction, at y1=y2=0, to see a Gaussian centered in (x1=1, x2=2). However, I see the mean/center at (x1=2,x2=0) instead.

What am I missing here? Is it how I define the grid to begin with?

For a 2d normal distribution it works as expected.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


xy_min = -5
xy_max = 5
npoints = 50
x = np.linspace(xy_min, xy_max, npoints)
dim = 4
xx1,yy1,xx2,yy2 = np.meshgrid(x, x,x,x)
points = np.concatenate([xx1[:, :,:, :,None], yy1[:, :, :,:,None],xx2[:, :, :,:,None],yy2[:, :, :,:,None]], axis=-1)

cov = np.diag(np.ones(4))
mean=np.array([1,0,2,0])
rv = multivariate_normal.pdf(points , mean=mean, cov=cov)

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(x, x, rv[:,0,:,0])
```

[image]

I tried to manually reshape the evaluation points first, but it gives the same results. So I think I am missing something conceptually here?

```
points_resh = np.reshape(points,[npoints**4,dim],order='C')
rv_resh = multivariate_normal.pdf(points_resh , mean=mean, cov=cov)
rv2 = np.reshape(rv_resh,[npoints,npoints,npoints,npoints],order='C')

plt.figure()
plt.contourf(x, x, rv2[:,0,:,0])
```

** EDIT: SOLVED **
using ij indexing for meshgrid everything works as expected. Only need to keep in mind that the matrix needs to be transposed for contour plotting. See example below:

```
#%% Instead use ij indexing

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 30)
z= np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
w= np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)

x4d,y4d,z4d,w4d= np.meshgrid(x, y,z,w,indexing='ij')
points4d= np.concatenate([x4d[:, :,:,:,None], y4d[:,  :,:,:,None], z4d[:, :,:,:,None],w4d[:, :,:,:,None]], axis=-1)



rv4d = multivariate_normal.pdf(points4d  , mean=[1,0.0,2,0.0],  cov=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(x,z,rv4d[:,0,:,0].T)
ax.set(xlabel='x',ylabel='y')
print(x_mean)
```

Comment: I solved it. It had to do with meshgird, that in the x,y ordering will order a 4d meshgrid like (y1, x1, x2,y2), which is very confuting. Better is to use ij indexing. I adapted the question

Answer (score 0):

using ij indexing for meshgrid everything works as expected. Only need to keep in mind that the matrix needs to be transposed for contour plotting. See example below:

```
#%% Instead use ij indexing

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 30)
z= np.linspace(-2, 2, 20)
w= np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)

x4d,y4d,z4d,w4d= np.meshgrid(x, y,z,w,indexing='ij')
points4d= np.concatenate([x4d[:, :,:,:,None], y4d[:,  :,:,:,None], z4d[:, :,:,:,None],w4d[:, :,:,:,None]], axis=-1)



rv4d = multivariate_normal.pdf(points4d  , mean=[1,0.0,2,0.0],  cov=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(x,z,rv4d[:,0,:,0].T)
ax.set(xlabel='x',ylabel='y')
print(x_mean)
```